# Normalizing a char array and removing extra characters (truncating)

Tags: c, arrays, normalization, truncate

I have the following code that I use to normalize a char array. At the end of the process, the normalized file has some of the old output leftover at the end. This is do to `i` reaching the end of the array before `j`. This makes sense but how do I remove the extra characters? I am coming from java so I apologize if I'm making mistakes that seem simple. I have the following code:

```
/* The normalize procedure normalizes a character array of size len 
   according to the following rules:
     1) turn all upper case letters into lower case ones
     2) turn any white-space character into a space character and, 
        shrink any n>1 consecutive whitespace characters to exactly 1 whitespace

     When the procedure returns, the character array buf contains the newly 
     normalized string and the return value is the new length of the normalized string.

     hint: you may want to use C library function isupper, isspace, tolower
     do "man isupper"
*/
int
normalize(unsigned char *buf,   /* The character array contains the string to be normalized*/
                    int len     /* the size of the original character array */)
{
    /* use a for loop to cycle through each character and the built in c funstions to analyze it */
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = len;

    if(isspace(buf[0])){
        i++;
        k--;
    }
    if(isspace(buf[len-1])){
        i++;
        k--;
    }
    for(i;i < len;i++){
        if(islower(buf[i])) {
            buf[j]=buf[i];
            j++;
        }
        if(isupper(buf[i])) {
            buf[j]=tolower(buf[i]);
            j++;
        }
        if(isspace(buf[i]) && !isspace(buf[j-1])) {
            buf[j]=' ';
            j++;
        }
        if(isspace(buf[i]) && isspace(buf[i+1])){
            i++;
            k--;
        }
    }

   return k;

}
```

Here is some sample output:

> halb mwqcnfuokuqhuhy ja mdqu nzskzkdkywqsfbs zwb lyvli HALB
>   MwQcnfuOKuQhuhy Ja mDQU nZSkZkDkYWqsfBS ZWb lyVLi

As you can see the end part is repeating. Both the new normalized data and old remaining un-normalized data is present in the result. How can I fix this?

Comment: Seeing (a) a sample *input*, (b) the corresponding sample *output*, (c) the *correct* sample output, and (d) all with about 1/10th the data presented here that *still produces the same problem* would be highly desirable. It would also be *much* easier for *you* to debug if you had all-of-the-above at your disposal.

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited the output to be shorter so it is easier to see the problem. After the normalized part the non-normalized part repeats.

Comment: Thank you. Just out of curiosity, when this assignment was given out, were you studying pointers and their many uses, because *can* be somewhat an exercise in walking two of them down your buffer. Just curious.

Comment: @WhozCraig We studied pointers a few weeks before this assignment was given out. While using pointers is somewhat part of the assignment that is not the purpose of the assignment.

Comment: Regarding your problem, it may be as simple as the assignment parameters themselves. It says nothing about terminating the string (i.e. setting a nulchar terminator); it simply says return the finalized length when done. In fact, there is no guarantees the *input* is terminated; why should the output be so? Put simply, your code may already be correct and your simply displaying the results incorrectly. That portion of the assignment is decidedly lacking imho.

Comment: `if(isspace(buf[0])){
        i++;
        k--;
  }` is not replaced by `' '`. `if(isspace(buf[len-1])){
        i++;
        k--;
    }` It has read and advances the position without inspection.

Comment: Just for info, [how to do this with pointers,](http://ideone.com/jLpVAm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a null terminator

```
k[newLength]='\0';
return k;
```

Comment: I believe you meant  `buf[j+1] = '\0'`
This does seem to accomplish a goal but adds an extra character to the end of the array (upon print out there is an X at the end). Did I add the pointer incorrectly?

Comment: Note: if the buffer passed is *not* a terminated string and the *last* char in the buffer is not a double-whitespace suffix, this can invoke UB.

Comment: It means if a packed buffer with no whitespace and ending in anything besides two whitespace chars (therefore the latter one being trimmed) will cause you to write to `buf[len]` for the terminator. The addressable region is `buf[0...(len-1)]`. That the length was passed to this function is no accident. There is nothing in assignment about anything being terminated. I honestly think the problem was in the *reporting* code, not the algorithm (though i didn't review the algorithm closely, admittedly). See my link in general comment for what i mean.

Comment: I am confused... I an not familiar with any domain requiring 2 white space chars aside from some formats. http headers etc.. what is the danger if copying the string "dog" into a char[4] buffer

Comment: I'm not apparently saying this right. There is nothing wrong with copying the string `dog` to a char buffer of length 4. There is a *significant* problem *terminating* the string `dog` in a character buffer of length **3**. Which this function *can* be given. `char buf[3] = { 'd', 'o', 'g' }; normalize(buf,3);` there is nothing in the assignment that says anything about termination of the string at all, and all you know about the buffer is you need to process `len` chars and return how many are there *after* normalization (which may still be `len`). I honestly can't say it clearer than that.

Answer (score 0):

to fix like this

```
int normalize(unsigned char *buf, int len) {
    int i, j;

    for(j=i=0 ;i < len; ++i){
        if(isupper(buf[i])) {
            buf[j++]=tolower(buf[i]);
            continue ;
        }
        if(isspace(buf[i])){
            if(!j || j && buf[j-1] != ' ')
                buf[j++]=' ';
            continue ;
        }
        buf[j++] = buf[i];
    }
    buf[j] = '\0';

    return j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or? add a null terminator

```
    k[newLength] = NULL;
    return k;
```